# Родственные ли слова?

Tags: словообразование

"Чары" (в значении "колдовство") и "чара" или "чарка" - есть ли что-то общее у этих слов или они просто созвучны?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Чары** «волшебство». Общеслав. Это форма мн. ч. др.-рус. **чаръ, чара** «колдовство» (отмечаются в памятниках XI—XIV вв.), которые восходят к праслав. *саrъ,* саrа «средство, помощь», из и.-е. *ker- «резать» > «делать» > «колдовать». В нем **k** перед **е** изменился в **с > ч**. (Этимологический словарь Цыганенко)

У Фасмера **чара** (чарка) считается родственным др.-инд. carus· "котел", греч. κερνος, κερνον "миска для жертвоприношений". Другие пытаются объяснить вост.-слав. слова как заимств. из тюрк. и видят источник в тат., алт., вост.-тюрк. čаrа "большая чаша", монг. čаrа. Вост. происхождение монг.-тюрк. слов не является ясным.

Слова просто созвучны, происхождение у них, как видите, разное.